# How to place TabView in Actionbar?

Tags: android

I am using tabview in my application. How to place tabview into Actionbar??

[like this...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cQ5HQ.png)

Would appreciate your help a lot!

Thanks

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ check out this